# MYSQL queries not executing or not showing errors

Tags: php, mysql

Just installed a nginx server with ubuntu 11.04 and after loading my php program i was writing i noticed that no MYSQL queries run. I get no errores, either from PHP nor MYSQL.

1. The user my PDO connection uses has all priviledges.
2. When i change the host to any value, i do not get any error either.

I believe mysql is not showing any connection error. How do i check it's enabled? Just checked mysql.conf and i see nothing related to error reporting. Also looked php.ini and all error options are enabled, i also enabled it in-code.

I have no clue, it's useless to work with no kind of error reporting!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where are your error logs for nginx?  Have you looked in those? Is mysql running? Try `service mysql status`.  PHP should still give you an error though if it can't connect to the database. How do you know the queries are not running?  What I mean is, what are the symptoms?  Maybe the queries *are* running but your input is bad?

Most important is to try to isolate the problem.  1) Use `curl -v http://your_server` to make sure nginx is actually serving the pages.  2) Set up a phpinfo.php file in the root web directory with `<? phpinfo(); ?>` and check the mysql settings and verify where log files for php are being written 3) Try installing phpmyadmin and see if you can connect to the database using that.

Each one of the above eliminates at least 1 of the elements (your program, PHP, nginx, mysql), helping you to narrow down the cause of your problem.

EDIT: Additional instructions for item 2.  You are looking for the php `error_log` setting. If it is not set, the errors should go to stderr, which in this case I think would be your nginx log files (true at least for apache).  You could also check that error_reporting is set to some reasonable value (try error_reporting=E_ALL for now).  You can set both of these in your php.ini file, or in your program.  See the manual in section [PHP Error Handling Runtime Configuration](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php).  I would do a sanity check by triggering an error in my program at the beginning of the program and making sure the error shows up in the log file:

```
trigger_error('Want to be a rock star test message', E_USER_WARNING);
```

If you see your message, you've got the right log file and you should find your other errors (if any - mysql might not be the problem, could be bad input as I mentioned before).

Comment: @Gabriel, did this answer your question?  I haven't seen any activity on this for a day.

Comment: Sorry Todd, had a flew and could't reply you!
1. Mysql is running.
2. My site is being served by NGINX.
3. PHPMYADMIN is working.
4. I'll check where the php logs are written!

Comment: Could not find the mysql log parameter or similar in the phpinfo report, care to tell me which is?

Comment: @Gabriel, you are looking for the `error_log` setting.  I've edited the question with more detailed instructions.